# How to Capture and show Image from Database php

Tags: php, html

I would like to retrieve images from phpmyadmin database. Currently, the link of the picture is saved in the database. But when I retrieve it, nothing was shown.

```
//form2.php (uploading of image)
<div>
<label>Attachment:</label><input type='file' name='img'><br>
</div>

//insert2.php
    <?php

    $con= mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');

    if(!$con)
    {
        echo 'Not Connected To Server';
    }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'satsform1'))
    {
        echo 'Database Not Selected';
    }

    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $staffno = $_GET['staffno'];
    $date = $_GET['date'];
    $time = $_GET['time'];
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $mobno = $_GET['mobno'];
    $roles = $_GET['roles'];
    $location = $_GET['location'];
    $flightno = $_GET['flightno'];
    $flightdate = $_GET['flightdate'];
    $seatno = $_GET['seatno'];
    $class = $_GET['class'];
    $description = $_GET['description'];
    $image = $_GET['img'];
    $remarks = $_GET['remarks'];






    $sql = "INSERT INTO handover (name,staffno,date,time,email,mobno,roles,location,flightno,flightdate,seatno,class,description,image,remarks,status) 
    VALUES ('$name','$staffno','$date','$time','$email','$mobno','$roles','$location','$flightno','$flightdate','$seatno','$class','$description','$image','$remarks','Pending')";

    if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        echo 'Not Submitted';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Submitted';
    }


    header("refresh:2; url=selection.php")

?>


      <?php
//fetch3.php
$connect = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','', 'satsform1');
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM handover 
  WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR staffno LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR date LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR email LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR mobno LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR roles LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR location LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR flightno LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR flightdate LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR seatno LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR class LIKE '%".$search."%'
 ";
}
else
{
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM handover ORDER BY ID
 ";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table bordered">
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Staff Name</th>
     <th>Staff Number</th>
     <th>Date</th>
     <th>Time</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Mobile Number</th>
     <th>Roles</th>
     <th>Location</th>
     <th>Flight Number</th>
     <th>Flight Date</th>
     <th>Seat Number</th>
     <th>Class of Travel</th>
     <th>Image</th>
     <th> Status </th>
    </tr>
 ';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["staffno"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["date"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["time"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["email"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["mobno"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["roles"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["location"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["flightno"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["flightdate"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["seatno"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["class"].'</td>
    <td><img src="'.$row["img"].'"></td> 
    <td>'.$row["status"].'</td>

    <td> <form action="edit3.php" method="GET">
     <input type="hidden" name="update_id" value="'.$row["ID"].'">
            <button type="submit">update </button>

        </form>
    </td>

   </tr> 
  ';
 }
 echo $output;
}
else
{
 echo 'Data Not Found';
}

?>
```

I expect the picture of a particular row will be shown and display the image.  So, when I doing the live search engine, the picture will appear under the image column according to their row.

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried to take some code out of this, but that's made the code you've posted invalid. Without proper code, my guess is the issue is you haven't exited the single quote string, so you're literally putting the string `<?php echo $row["img"]; ?>...` inside the `src` attribute instead of the value.

Comment: After your edit, the `<img>` tag is missing its closing `>`.

Comment: What do you mean with `live search engine`? Do you mean the picture is shown on production server but not on testing development? What is the value of `$row["img"]`? It seems that this is a typographical error. Also consider please for your next question to use a shorter example. The insert and search query don't seem relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please change this:

```
<td><img src="'.$row["img"].'"</td>
```

To this:

```
<td><img src="'.$row["img"].'"></td>
```

Hope this help.